# Heroku taking 2 seconds to load every page--including pages that simply render a single text string

Tags: ruby, performance, heroku

No, this is NOT the "my page doesn't have any traffic and it has to be reloaded" issue.

We have 4 dynos for an alpha application. The reason we do, is because each page takes over 2 seconds to load.  Even little things like rendering a text string (no layouts, erb or anything).

If I watch our logs, for our longer queries, they report response times in the 300-700ms range--which is far shorter than 2 seconds.

The DNS is cached, and the collective time to load given that isn't a slow DNS issue. And, that shouldn't affect subsequent page loads, right?

Any thoughts on how to get to the bottom of this would be appreciated.

Here are two screenshots to show what I mean.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7175041/Screenshots/qo.png

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7175041/Screenshots/qq.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd do is to switch on NewRelic Basic - it's a free performance monitor integrated with Heroku. That'll help you get a bearing on the basics of where the trouble is coming from.

I take it that you don't see similar results locally? If you don't, then skip this step, but if you do, you can also run NewRelic locally and interrogate all of your queries for response times.

I'd stay away from using things like the Benchmark library - that was my first thought in troubleshooting a speed issue, but Benchmark is necessarily going to ignore elements of your app that are outside the pure Ruby layer, and if that's where you're slow then NewRelic catches that anyway.

Finally, if all else fails, a support ticket with Heroku's team has always been extremely helpful to me. Just make sure you check the box that lets them clone your app, it makes things a lot easier for them.

Let us know what you find out - I'm curious to see what the particular gremlin is!

Comment: I've got a ticket open with Heroku. They told me to install NewRelic. I installed NewRelic, but it doesn't match the timing I'm seeing in the logs (and on my local).  I will investigate locally as well, to see if it's on my local (non development load). That's actually what it's like, like my system is doing an "autoreload" for production mode as well..

Comment: I've checked it in NewRelic local, and it only shows a 16ms load time.